# Does IBM Waston personality insight API support simplied Chinese?

Tags: ibm-watson, personality-insights, watson-personality-insights

I'm trying to use personality insight API by IBM to get personality and value scores from social media posts in simplified Chinese language.

I find that they do support the Chinese language in the API document, but I get the error when I try to hit API.

Error info is:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "sub_code": "C00001",
    "error": "The language you requested, zh-cn, is not supported. Languages 
              supported: en,es,ja,ar,ko."
}
```

Can anyone figure this out, what's wrong? Am I using API in wrong way?

Comment: Seems like they are not supporting the Chinese language at the moment. Can you share the link where you read that they support the Chinese language in the personality API ?

Comment: here's the link to its API documentation.https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/personality-insights?topic=personality-insights-input&locale=en

Answer (score 0):

The entry for supported languages in the service documentation shows

```
Table 2. Specifying request and response languages
Language             Argument   Supported by Content-Language   Supported by Accept-Language 

Simplified Chinese    zh-cn          No                             Yes
```

ie. Chinese isn't supported for input text, but it is supported as the output report. So you can specify Spanish as the language of the text that you want to analyse, and request the analysis report back in Chinese.